# Add all parameters with parameter pack expansion

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Consider I have a variadic template with `int...` parameters. For example a function like this:

```
template<int... t>
int add(){
    return t... + ???
}
```

All the method should do is adding all the parameters. It can be easily achieved using recursive variadic templates. However, is it also possible expressing this (or something similar like using other binary operators to aggregate all the template parameters) using parameter pack expansion?

Comment: No. Just do it the way it can be easily achieved.

Comment: Okay, I just thought it might be even easier and better comprehensible with parameter pack expansion :)

Comment: The problem with the other solutions is they calculate the addition in execution time.

Comment: @Peregring-lk: You are right, that is an important fact!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, using a trick I learnt from @Xeo in the Lounge. I originally used it to make a variadic "print" template function.

```
#include <iostream>

template<int... ints>
int add()
{
  int result = 0;
  using expand_variadic_pack  = int[]; // dirty trick, see below
  (void)expand_variadic_pack{0, ((result += ints), void(), 0)... };
  // first void: silence variable unused warning
  // uses braced-init-list initialization rules, which evaluates
  //  the elements inside a braced-init-list IN ORDER, to repetetively
  //  execute a certain operation
  // second void is to prevent malicious "operator," overloads, which
  //  cannot exist for void types
  // 0 at the end is to handle empty variadic pack (zero-size array initializer is illegal.
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << add<1,2,3,4>() << '\n';
}
```

This works on every compiler that has decent C++11 support (GCC 4.8+, Clang 3.2+, MSVS2013, ...)

Comment: Not sure whether to laugh or cry

Comment: @Lightness surely you've abused side-effects of expressions before in c++.

Comment: Of course! 

Comment: This should also work (and look a bit cleaner) with `auto a = {(ret += ints)... }; (void)a;`

Comment: What's the first 0 within brace-init-list used for?

Comment: @Peregring-lk if the parameter pack is empty, a zero-sized array is initialized, which is illegal. For a more thorough explanation of what is really going on, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339789/how-to-call-a-function-on-all-variadic-template-args?lq=1).

Comment: This approach also works for variadic input parameters, eg: `template<typename... T> int add(T... ints)`: https://ideone.com/UtS43M

Answer (score 8):

One possible variant which uses lambda and `std::accumulate`:

```
#include <array>
#include <numeric>

template <int... t>
int add()
{
    return [](const std::array<int, sizeof...(t)>& a)
    {
        return std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0);
    }({t...});
}
```

Comment: This one looks clean and much less of a hack! Unfortunately, computations are unlikely to be optimized in compile time.