# Shortening multi-variable Comparisons

Tags: c++

**[This is for a project that has a length limit, hence the question]**

I have a function meant to return how many variables passed are equivalent to zero.

```
int countZeros(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int zeros = 0;
    if(a == 0)
    {
        zeros++;
    }
    if(b == 0)
    {
        zeros++;
    }
    if(c == 0)
    {
        zeros++;
    }
    if(d == 0)
    {
        zeros++;
    }
    return(zeros);
}
```

The code functions perfectly fine but is very long for what it is achieving. Is it possible to do the same thing using a for loop?

Ex: `for each 0 in [data-set]{zeros++;}`?

I realize I could use a for loop while calling the function to test each variable, but the function is called inside of a variable declaration:

```
addavg[x][y] = ((varA + varB + varC + varD + nums[x][y]) / (5 - (countZeros(varA, varB, varC, varD))));
```

Comment: Why are those numbers not in an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a variadic function?  It will take any number of ints.

This example uses fold-expressions to make the code shorter, and easier to read.

```
template <typename ...Ts> 
int countZeros(Ts ...ts)
{
   return ( !ts + ...);
}
```

Additionally, you have this example use case

```
addavg[x][y] = ((varA + varB + varC + varD + nums[x][y]) / (5 - (countZeros(varA, varB, varC, varD))));
```

You can use the same technique as above to write

```
template <typename ...Ts> 
int sum(Ts ...ts)
{
   return (ts + ...);
}
```

and then your example becomes

```
addavg[x][y] = ((sum(varA, varB, varC, varD) + nums[x][y]) / (5 - (countZeros(varA, varB, varC, varD))));
```

Comment: Note that fold expressions were added in C++17, so these examples won't work for C++11 or C++14.

Answer (score 3):

One simple option would be just

```
return ((a == 0) + (b == 0) + (c == 0) + (d == 0));
```

Depending on what the requirements of your project are. For a more general approach, have a look at using `va_list` to accept any number of integers into your function. In that case yes, you would want a loop.

Comment: `va_list` is the C way to do this, and it is not type-safe.  In C++, a variadic template is safer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't pay enough attention to the tags, and thought this was a C question

Answer (score 2):

For your specific example, you could shorten it to something like this:

```cpp
int countZeros(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return int(a == 0) + int(b == 0) + int(c == 0) + int(d == 0);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/UJe0iZ)

However, a variadic template function would be a better way to go, then you can pass in as many parameters as you want.

[@cigien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60875646/65863) shows you how to use [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), which were added in C++17.  But if you are using C++11 or C++14 instead, you can still use a variadic template function, you would just have to loop over the parameters manually (see [How can I iterate over a packed variadic template argument list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230621/)), eg:

```cpp
template <typename... Args> 
int countZeros(Args... args)
{
    int zeros = 0;
    for(int i : {args...}) {
        zeros += int(i == 0);
    }
    return zeros;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/mFjSHC)

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename... Args> 
int countZeros(Args... args)
{
    std::array<int, sizeof...(args)> a = {args...};
    return std::count_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [](int i){ return (i == 0); });
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/EKOi8H)

Alternatively:

```cpp
// for when the template parameter pack is empty...
int doCountZeros() {
    return 0;
}

template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
int doCountZeros(Arg firstArg, Args... otherArgs) {
    return int(firstArg == 0) + doCountZeros(otherArgs...);
}

template <typename... Args>
int countZeros(Args... args) {
    return doCountZeros(args...);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/sIEW0n)

Any of these approaches will happily handle your example of `countZeros(varA, varB, varC, varD)`.

---

Your example also shows the summing of the 4 variables together.  That can be handled with a function as well, eg:

```cpp
int sum(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return a + b + c + d;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/2YomVu)

Or better, via a variadic function.  If you are not using C++17 fold expressions, you can loop through the parameters manually, similar to shown above (also see [Add all parameters with parameter pack expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628876/)), eg:

```cpp
template <typename... Args> 
int sum(Args... args)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i : {args...}) {
        result += i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/to4Rb3)

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <numeric>

template <typename... Args> 
int sum(Args... args)
{
    std::array<int, sizeof...(args)> a = {args...};
    return std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/kgcnGY)

Alternatively:

```cpp
int doSum() {
    return 0;
}

template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
int doSum(Arg firstArg, Args... otherArgs) {
    return firstArg + doSum(otherArgs...);
}

template <typename... Args>
int sum(Args... args) {
    return doSum(args...);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/wDiEBR)

Any of these approaches will let you use `sum(varA, varB, varC, varD)` where needed.