# Iterating on a tuple... again

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++14

It's been a while that I've been doing C++ but I'm not familiar with templates.

Recently, I tried to write a class that wrap a `std::vector<std::tuple<Types...>>`. This class must have member functions, and I really need to be able to *iterate* over the tuple. In fact, if I am able to print every element of a tuple (in the order), I would be able to do everything I need.

I found a solution using a cast, but I'm not really confident with it since it is based on a cast that I don't really like (plus, when I try to use `static_cast`, it doesn't compile anymore).

My question is, is the following code correct, portable, is it a hack and should I find another way to do this than to use this cast ? Also, this cast is probably a runtime-cast right ? Is there a way to do what I want without this ?

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::tuple<> const& tuple)
{
    return out; // Nothing to do here
}

template<typename First, typename... Types>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::tuple<First, Types...> const& tuple)
{
    out << std::get<0>(tuple) << " ";

    // The cast that I don't like
    return out << (std::tuple<Types...>&) tuple;
}

int main()
{
    auto tuple = std::make_tuple(1, 2.3, "Hello");
    std::cout << tuple << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: That cast looks like a `reinterpret_cast`. So no, not good.

Comment: This even [produces a segfault](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f96f1e786b070f1) when using clang++ & libc++

Comment: @dyp That's exactly what I wanted to know, thanks !

Comment: I suggest also having a look at Boost.Fusion (esp. `for_each`). It may or may not be overkill, but it certainly is easier to write.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`std::index_sequence_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) for fun and profit.

```
template <typename TupleLike, size_t ... Inds>
std::ostream& PrintHelper(std::ostream& out, TupleLike const& tuple, std::index_sequence<Inds...>)
{
  int unused[] = {0, (void(out << std::get<Inds>(tuple) << " "), 0)...};
  (void)unused;
  return out;
}

template<typename... Types>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::tuple<Types...> const& tuple)
{
  return PrintHelper(out, tuple, std::index_sequence_for<Types...>());
}
```

EDIT : [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b7e3f802d050752). Thanks to @dyp. This uses an expansion trick from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110699/what-does-this-variadic-template-code-do).

Comment: Note that this causes stack corruption on MSVC, but the equivalent using `std::array<>` works fine.

Comment: VC++ 2015 has fixed the stack corruption issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do what I want. I used [this article](http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/iteratingoverastdtuple/) that can print the elements of a tuple in the descending order, and I use a second index `J == std::tuple_size<std::tuple<Types...>>::value - I` so I can specialize the template when `I==0`.

```
template<std::size_t I, std::size_t J, typename... Types>
struct printHelper
{
    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& out, std::tuple<Types...> const& tuple)
    {
        out << std::get<J>(tuple) << " ";

        // Recursive call without cast
        return printHelper<I-1,J+1,Types...>{}(out, tuple);
    };
};

// Specialization on the last element when I==0
template<std::size_t J, typename... Types>
struct printHelper<0,J,Types...>
{
    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& out, std::tuple<Types...> const& tuple)
    {
        // Nothing to do here
        return out;
    }
};

template<typename... Types>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::tuple<Types...> const& tuple)
{
    return printHelper<std::tuple_size<std::tuple<Types...>>::value, 0, Types...>{}(out, tuple);
}
```