# Call void function for each template type in a variadic templated function?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

My goal is to write a simple generic function for registering converters for arbitrary C++ types. For simplicity I'll just print C++ type names. I'd like to be able to call my generic `print_type_name` function for any types, including multiple types at once (variadic):

```
template <typename T>
void print_type_name(void)
{
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}
```

This works fine for things like this:

```
print_type_name<int>();
print_type_name<std::string>();
print_type_name<std::vector<std::complex<float> > >();
```

However, I need to be able to call this function for each type in a variadic template, e.g. (when expanded):

```
print_type_name<int, std::string, std::vector<std::complex<float> > >();
```

Here's what I've come up with, but it's rather clunky:

```
template <typename ...TS>
void noop(TS... ts) { }

template <typename T>
int real_print_type_name(void) {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

template <typename ...TS>
void print_type_name(void) {
    noop(real_print_type_name<TS>()...);
}
```

Which allows for the following:

```
template <typename ...TS>
void other_function(void) {
    print_type_name<TS...>();
}
```

Notice the useless `noop` function and the `int` return type of
`real_print_type_name`, both of which I had to add in order to expand
the parameter pack. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this variadic template code do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110699/what-does-this-variadic-template-code-do)

Comment: can be done inside `print_type_name` with something like: `int dummy[] = {0, (real_print_type_name<TS>(), 0)...};`

Comment: @Pradhan: Since the code in that question is a bad idea, and this is asking for **good** code, that's not a duplicate.

Comment: @MSalters Agreed. However, the answer to that question addresses those issues and gives a good version solving OPs problem. As a plus, it builds up to the final solution in a very logical sequence. So while the questions aren't duplicates, the answers will be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <typename ...TS>
void print_type_name() {
    using expander = int[];
    (void) expander{ 0, (std::cout << typeid(TS).name() << '\n', 0)... };
}
```

Or, C++17-style:

```
template <typename ...TS>
void print_type_name(void) {
    (std::cout << ... << (typeid(TS).name() + "\n"s));
}
```

[Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hXYlIwszhK55N51C).

Comment: C++17?? Never heard of it. I haven't even gotten very familiar with C++11 yet, let alone C++14 :(

Comment: @RemyLebeau The dark voodoo `(std::cout << ... << (typeid(TS).name() + "\n"s));` is a [*fold-expression*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4191.html) recently incorporated into the [C++17 Working Paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf). T.C. traveled back in time to post this answer assuring us that (1) C++17 will be completed on schedule and (2) the feature will still be in the standard in 2017. (Although I would personally eschew the string concatenation and go with `((std::cout << typeid(TS).name() << '\n'), ...);` instead.)

Comment: @Casey I'd say (2) is highly likely especially as the Concepts TS also depends on it. I like to be optimistic about (1) now that we did get C++14 finished on schedule :P (Also, N4191's wording is backwards in some places; you'd want the [final revision](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4295.html).) And I agree, not concatenating is better, I just wanted to show off the binary fold ;)

Comment: I'll use your first example. I'd venture to say it's not self-explanatory but it's the simplest and it works when you only have types.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a helper function.  It uses random dark magic, but its name is pretty clear:

```
void do_in_order() {}

template<class...Fs>
void do_in_order( Fs&&...fs ) {
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{0, (void(
    std::forward<Fs>(fs)()
  ),0)... };
}
```

or in C++17:

```
template<class...Fs>
void do_in_order( Fs&&...fs ) {
  (void(std::forward<Fs>(fs)())...);
}
```

(much nicer).

which hides any uglyness.  It takes a set of `void()` callables and calls 
them left to right -- it does the tasks in order, like it says on the tin.

Then `print_type_names` becomes:

```
template<class...Ts>
void print_type_names() {
  do_in_order( print_type_name<Ts>... );
}
```

or

```
template<class...Ts>
void print_type_names() {
  do_in_order( [&]{
    std::cout << typeid(Ts).name() << std::endl;
  }... );
}
```

if you don't want to use the single `print_type_name` function and want to inline it.

Note that some non-conforming compilers complain about having an entire lambda be expanded in a `...`.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f83d2cf12c755098)

Comment: And with C++17 around the corner, the ugliness can be [_**folded**_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) into `(std::forward<Fs>(fs)(), ...);`

Comment: @bit2 no `(void)`?

Comment: `do_in_order` becomes just `template<typename... Fs> void do_in_order(Fs&&... fs) { (std::forward<Fs>(fs)(), ...); }`.
There's nothing to noop with `(void)`.

Comment: @bit2shift Whatever `fs()` returns could have `operator,` overloaded.  Are you claiming that fold expressions on `,` never invoke `operator,`?  If so, do you have a link to the paper?  Otherwise, in generic code you need to `( void(std::forward<Fs>(fs)()), ...);` to `void` the return value of `fs()` and make `operator,` safe.  `struct evil_comma { template<class T> int operator,( T&& t ) const { std::cout << "I am evil" << std::endl; exit(-1); } };`, as an example.

Comment: I'm not saying you should overload `operator,`, but you shouldn't overload `operator,`. Rumour has it that [the overloaded `,` can now guarantee sequencing in C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).

Comment: @bit2shift I am saying generic code cannot assume `operator,` is **not** overloaded.  Your code seems to assume this.  I do not know if this is because you are screwing up, or if you know something I do not, which is why I am asking.

Comment: Here's the catch: if the overloaded `operator,`'s argument is a value/rvalue reference, `do_in_order(func_a, func_b, func_c, func_d);` will evaluate the functions in the order (D, C, B, A). But if it's an lvalue reference, the order will be (A, B, C, D).
[Try playing with the references in the overloaded operator](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f92d3941c9a3eec).

Comment: The gist of it is: either pay attention to the operator's signature or play it safe with the `void()` cast.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this:

```
void print_type_name()
{
    std::cout<<"\n";
}

template <typename T>
void print_type_name(const T& t)
{
    std::cout<<t<<" : of type "<<typeid(t).name()<<"\n";
}

template <typename T1, typename... Ts>
void print_type_name(const T1& t1, const Ts&... ts)
{
    // Head
    std::cout<<t1<<" : of type "<<typeid(t1).name()<<", ";
    // Tail
    print_type_name(ts...);
}
```

Whether it's clearer or not I don't know.

Comment: Obvious typo removed - you had `std::cout` twice for the tail. But you may want to consider if type deduction will work as intended here: passing an `int&` will deduce `int` instead.

Comment: @MSalters: indeed, will decltype help here?

Comment: @MSalters `typeid` strips reference-ness and cv-qualification anyway.

Comment: According to Scott Meyers (effective modern c++ item 4) the result of typeid(t).name() is implementation dependent

Comment: `typeid(cv T&)`  and `typeid(cv T)` are both specified to be the same as `typeid(T)`. What string `.name()` produces is implementation-dependent.

Comment: It's important that each templated version of the function work using only the types, i.e. no instances are passed to the function.
The usage of `typeid` to print type names was purely for example (and irrelevant).

Comment: That's ok, it can still work, the above doesn't need to invoke on instance, you can peel off templates just based on types unpacking

Comment: Then `print_type_name<int>()` becomes ambiguous (`T=int`, or `T1=int, Ts=<>`).