# Explicit operator<< selects 'wrong' overload

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm playing around with variadic templates, and wrote this, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17340003/2064196) :

```
template <size_t... I>
void print(seq<I...>)
{
    decltype(std::cout) * dummy[sizeof...(I)] = { &(std::cout << I << ' ')... };
}
```

Because `std::cout::operator<<` has a return type, it can be stored, so there's no need for the `( ,0)` comma trick.

Now, to shut up the "unused variable 'dummy'" warning, and to print a newline, I tried the following statements, but they didn't do what I wanted:

```
dummy[0]->operator <<('\n'); // prints 10
```

(apparently called `operator<<(int)` instead of `operator<<(char)`

```
dummy[0]->operator <<("\n"); // prints a pointer
```

(apparently called `operator<<(const void*)` instead of `operator<<(const char*)`

In the end, I had to write

```
*dummy[0] << '\n';             // prints a newline as desired
```

My question is, why did the "wrong" overloads get chosen?

Comment: What does `std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(std::cout),decltype(std::ostream)>::value<<'\n';` print?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "wrong" overloads are chosen because [only some overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) are members of `std::ostream` class. The overloads for `char` and `const char*` are not members of `std::ostream`, but [free functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), so, in

```
*dummy[0] << '\n';
```

argument-dependent lookup will find `operator<<(std::ostream&, char)`, but in

```
dummy[0]->operator <<('\n');
```

only member functions will be considered, resulting in `std::ostream::operator<<(int)` being called.