# Potentially returning different types of objects from a single method

Tags: c++, c++11, return-type

I am in charge of refactoring some code which parses similar (but different files). They are different in that they have a different number of columns. Let's say the file types are called `MODEL_FILE`and `COMPANY_FILE`.
`MODEL_FILE` has the following format:

```
CAR_MODEL    CAR_COMPANY    MILEAGE
```

`COMPANY_FILE` has the following format:

```
CAR_COMPANY    MILEAGE
```

The result of parsing a `MODEL_FILE` would be `std::map<Car_Model, std::map<Car_Company, double> >` ; the result of parsing a `COMPANY_FILE` would be `std::map<Car_Company, double>`.

The header file is something like this:

```
typedef std::map<Car_Model, std::map<Car_Company, double> > Model_Data;
typedef std::map<Car_Company, double> Company_Data;

struct Data
{
    Model_Data data_model;
    Company_Data data_company;
};

bool parse_company_file(const std::string& path, Company_Data& data); // 1
bool parse_model_file(const std::string& path, Model_Data& data); // 2
bool parse_generic_file(bool is_company_file, const std::string& path, Data& data); // 3
```

The parsing code really is in `3`. Both `1` and `2` internally invoke `3`, which knows (through the boolean parameter) whether the file it's going to parse has 2 or 3 columns. Only one of the fields in the `Data` will get filled (which one depending on the bool parameter). Then, the function calling `3` will retrieve the appropriate field of the struct from the filled `Data` struct and use to populate the map it has been passed.

In this way, the code for parsing the file in only in one place (`3`). From the outside, the code is fine (two different entry points which return the appropriate data), but the internal implementation doesn't look right to me (the trick of using the struct as a way of having a single method used to potentially populate two different and independent types of objects).

I have thought of using inheritance, so that the generic method receives a pointer to a common base class which has two methods (`add_model_data()` and `add_company_data()`). It would invoke one or the other depending of the `bool` param. However, this is more complex and confusing, and implies breaking the abstraction by having the base class be aware of the methods of lower classes, it's prone to errors, etc.

The question is, **is it possible to somehow retain the parsing logic in a single place but use a different (and arguably better) approach than a `struct` in order to deal with different files?**

Comment: `std::map<Car_Model, Car_Company, double>` makes no sense.

Comment: when you say `std::map<Car_Model, Car_Company, double>` do you actually mean a `std::map<Car_Model,std::pair<Car_Company, double>>` ? The third parameter is the comparator, so actually it shouldnt compile with `double` as third parameter

Comment: My bad, it's a map of maps. I have edited the question.

Comment: Did you try making the parse_generic_file function actually generic (i.e. template function)? Seems like it could solve the problem. Also in your current implementation, the return value should rather be a union not a struct. This would make the code more expressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::variant` and `boost::variant` are designed for "or" types -- a type that is A or B.  So that is one approach.

Another far fancier approach would be to remember that there are 3 numbers -- 0, 1 and infinity.

This approach is harder, but refactors your parsing code into being very generic.  I wouldn't bother with this solution, so I'm just sketching it below, but it would let you add a 4 or 20 column version of this format with minimal work once you've written it.

A column parser takes a string and returns a value of type T:

```
std::string -> T
```

or

```
template<class T>
using column_parser = std::function<T(std::string)>;
```

(We can make it more efficient later).

Given N column parsers, we can build a `map<T0, map<T1, map<T2, map<..., map<TN-2, TN-1>...>>>>`.

```
template<class T0, class...Ts>
struct nested_map {
  using type=T0;
};
template<class T0, class...Ts>
using nested_map_t = typename nested_map<T0, Ts...>::type;

template<class T0, class T1, class...Ts>
struct nested_map<T0, T1, Ts...> {
  using type=std::map<T0, nested_map_t<T1, Ts...>>;
};
```

That lets us take a pack of types and generate a map.

```
template<class...Ts>
nested_map_t<Ts...> parse_file(std::string path, column_parser<Ts...> columns);
```

This parses any number of columns into a nested map.

You expose:

```
bool parse_company_file(const std::string& path, Company_Data& data) {
  column_parser<Car_Company> company = // TODO
  column_parser<double> milage = // TODO
  try {
    data = parse_file( path, company, milage );
  } except (some_error) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
bool parse_model_file(const std::string& path, Model_Data& data) {
  column_parser<Car_Model> model = // TODO
  column_parser<Car_Company> company = // TODO
  column_parser<double> milage = // TODO
  try {
    data = parse_file( path, model, company, milage );
  } except (some_error) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Now, to write `parse_file`, we do something like (pseudocode)

```
template<class...Ts>
nested_map_t<Ts...> parse_file(std::string path, column_parser<Ts...> columns) {
  nested_map_t<Ts...> retval;

  auto f = open_file(path);

  for( std::string line: get_lines(f)) {
    std::vector<std::string> column_data = split_into_columns(line);
    if (sizeof...(Ts) != column_data.size()) throw some_error;
    index_upto<sizeof...(Ts)>()([&](auto...Is){
      recursive_insert(retval, columns(column_data[Is])...);
    });
  }
  return retval;
}
```

where `index_upto` is either [this in C++14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42934850/1774667) or replaced by a manual pack expansion and helper function, and `recursive_insert(m, t0, ts...)` takes a "nested map" `M& m` and a bunch of elements `T const&` and recursively does `recursive_insert(m[t0], ts...)` until there is 1 element and it does `m = t0`.

Comment: Awesome reply, thanks for the hard work. `boost::variant` did the trick :)