# Execute a function on each element of a list of types that's not in a parameter pack?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I've been playing with template metaprogramming lately, and I've found myself with a list of types and a helper `TypeList`, and I need to call a function on each element of the `TypeList`... I feel like I'm missing something obvious / clean because what I've started creating is quite ugly.

I'm likely not using the perfect terminology, but this minimal example below has, commented out, what I'm trying to do. I'm not sure if I'm missing any "clean" approach, since the arguments are already in a `TypeList` and are not themselves a variadic parameter pack.

```
template<typename... Types>
struct TypeList { constexpr static int size = sizeof...(Types); };

class Foo {
 private:
  template<typename T>
  const T& Get() {
    // ...
  }
 public:
  template <typename T>  
  void DoThingWithManyTypes(T* t) {
    // T::types is a TypeList<...>
    // for each type in T::types {
    //   t->DoThing(Get<type>());
    // }  
  }
};
```

I was trying to solve this entirely in `Foo`, since I (think?) this is much easier if I make `Get` public and then use partial template specialization on a new class outside of `Foo` -- but then I'd be making `Get` public (or use friend functions), which I'm trying to work around.

Comment: `in T::types` What `T::types`? Please post an example. You mean `T` is specialized to be `TypeList`?

Comment: `T` is a class which has inside of it `using types = TypeList<...>` where `...` is some set of types.

Comment: Please add that relevant information to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339789/how-to-call-a-function-on-all-variadic-template-args With `template <typename T...>  
  void DoThingWithManyTypes(TypeList<T....>* t) {` does answer your question?

Comment: @cigien It already is (I thought?), in the comment `// T::types is a TypeList<...>`

I'll look into that right now, @KamilCuk , thanks.

Comment: That works, thanks @KamilCuk!

Comment: Since the linked question answers your question, I've closed it as a duplicate.